# Отправка данных методом get в yii2 используя ActiveForm

Tags: yii2

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой. Есть форма

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'id' => 'search-form',
    'action' => 'site/search',
    'method' => 'get',
    'enableClientValidation' => false,
    'enableAjaxValidation' => false
])?>
<?= $form->field($searchModel, 'request')->label(false)->textInput(['placeholder' => 'Search', 'size' => 12]) ?>
<?php ActiveForm::end() ?>
```

отправляя форму попадаю по адресу `http://yii.loc/site/search?Search%5Brequest%5D=my_request` меня интересует что это за `Search%5Brequest%5D` как он формируется и как мне отформатировать урл до вида `http://yii.loc/site/search?search=my_request`

Comment: В соответствии с кодировкой ascii имеем: %5b = [ и %5d = ], т.е.URL приобретает вид http://yii.loc/site/search?Search[request]=my_request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Search%5Brequest%5D` = `Search[request]`

- **Search** - название модели
- **request** - название поля в модели

данное название формирует метод `ActiveForm::field()` для поля input (в данном случае)

Что бы изменить имя, передайте параметр `name` в массив `options` метода `textInput()`

`->textInput(['placeholder' => 'Search', 'size' => 12, 'name'=>'search'])`

Или используйте [Html::textInput()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml.html#textInput()-detail)

`Html::textInput('search', $searchModel->request, ['placeholder' => 'Search', 'size' => 12])`